# How to specify script type in .js file?

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

In html files, you probably can write:

`<script  type="aaa/bbb" src="xyz.js"></script>` <del>language="javascript"</del>

In JavaScript files (.js) it is just the raw JavaScript codes without specifying the type, is it assuming all types are "text/javascript"? What if you have typed like "aaa/bbb"?

Dojo is an example may require this.

Comment: @frank_neff: Are you sure? That's [not what the HTML5 spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element), and one of the things the HTML5 spec is about is documenting the things most browsers do.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I know that Webkit browsers (like chrome) will do. Sorry, but i think a "HTML5 spec." is not a good reference, because it's taged as "work in progrss". And HTML5 is not a Standard yet. But back to topic: I'm not 100% shure, so I will delete my comment ;)

Comment: @frank_neff: The HTML5 spec is indeed a work in progress (and like sausage, if you like it, whatever you do *don't* subscribe to the mailing list and watch it get made). Parts of it are speculative and subject to change, but the parts describing the things that have been around for a long time *mostly* do a good job of documenting what the browsers actually do rather than what the HTML4 spec said they should do. :-) I'm curious: What scripting languages other than JavaScript does Chrome support? I'm curious enough to test this, but I can't see how, as I thought it just supported JavaScript.

Comment: @frank_neff: Thought of a way to test it: Include JavaScript code, but in a resource carrying a different MIME type. And Chrome seems to follow the HTML5 spec rather than looking at the `Content-Type` of the response. I served JavaScript with various content types (`text/plain`, `text/html`, `text/vbscript`, `application/vbscript`) and Chrome treated it as JavaScript every time. Example: http://www.crowdersoftware.com/scripttest2.html I even tried IE and served up actual VBScript with the MIME type `text/vbscript`, but it also tried to run it as JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in a JavaScript file you just write the code without any tags around it. It's the tag that includes the file in the page that specifies the type. So you might have:

foo.js:

```
function doSomethingReallyCool() {
   // ...
}
```

...which you include like this:

```
<script src="foo.js"></script>
```

You can optionally specify the `type` on the [`script` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>
```

...but in practice this is unnecessary for JavaScript, you'd only need it if you were referencing a file that *wasn't* JavaScript (like VBScript on IE).

Note that the `language` attribute in your example was never part of any specification. Since HTML 4 (12 years ago), the correct way to indicate the language is via the `type` attribute.